# How can I format 51.xx.xx.xx:33xxx:user:pass into user:pass@51.xx.xx.xx:33xxx

Tags: javascript, node.js, formatting, proxies

This is what I have so far but it returns only one proxy because it rewrites over it x (however many proxies) times. I do not want to make a new file but instead rewrite proxies.txt with every proxy.

```
const fs = require("fs");

const formatProxies = () => {
  const rawProxies = fs.readFileSync("./proxies.txt", "utf-8");
  const split = rawProxies.trim().split("\n");

  for (const p of split) {
    const parts = p.trim().split(":");
    const [ip, port, user, pass] = parts;
    fs.writeFileSync(
      "./proxies.txt",
      user + ":" + pass + "@" + ip + ":" + port + "\r\n",
      { encoding: "utf8" }
    );
  }
};
formatProxies();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
const fs = require("fs");

const formatProxies = () => {
  const rawProxies = fs.readFileSync("./proxies.txt", "utf-8");
  const split = rawProxies.trim().split("\n");

  const lines = []
  for (const p of split) {
    const parts = p.trim().split(":");
    const [ip, port, user, pass] = parts;
    lines.push(user + ":" + pass + "@" + ip + ":" + port)
  }
  fs.writeFileSync(
    "./proxies.txt",
    lines.join("\r\n"),
    { encoding: "utf8" }
  );
};
formatProxies();
```

Comment: this works! thanks just need to wait a few to accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Node.js has [fs.appendFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options), which writes to the end of the file instead of overwriting the whole thing.

Comment: If you want to empty the file before you write the entries to it, you could use fs.truncateSync; but that's a problem, because if your script stops somehow between emptying the file and appending the results, you've lost the file. twharmon's solution works well.